# mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory

Tags: mount, fstab, btrfs, swap

I cannot mount the swap subvolue.

-> `sudo mount -av`

```
/                        : ignored
/home                    : already mounted
mount: /swap: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

-> fstab

```
# <file system>                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>                                                               <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/cryptsystem         /               btrfs   ssd,noatime,space_cache,compress=zstd,subvol=@                          0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptsystem         /home           btrfs   ssd,noatime,space_cache,compress=zstd,subvol=@home                      0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptsystem         /swap           btrfs   ssd,noatime,compress=no,subvol=@swap                                    0       0
```

-> btrfs subvolumes

```
ID 257 gen 427049 top level 5 path @home
ID 272 gen 427049 top level 5 path @
ID 3194 gen 425853 top level 272 path @swap
```

Comment: Two things to point out: 1) If mounting as a normal filesystem, check if `/swap` exists. 2) If mounting as a swap volume, the `fstab` syntax is slightly different: the mount point needs to be 'none' and the fs type needs to be 'swap'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Mount the btrfs volume at `/mnt` (e.g from a live iso) and then create the `@swap` subvolume as `/mnt/@swap`.

### Details of the Initial Problem:

Turns out that the btrfs subvolume `@swap` has not been a top-level subvolume as needed for the mount operation. This is indicated by the integer `272` in the subvolume list.
This is the result of creating the `@swap` subvolume under `/` while this was referring to the `@` subvolume. For this reason, `@swap` was really created as `@/@swap` (don't know if that's a neologism).